# Mathematica: Plot the derivative of a piecewise function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, piecewise

I'm trying to plot the derivative of a mollifier function in Mathematica. It differentiates the function OK, and can plot the function using `%`, but I would like to be able to plot by assigning the derivative to be a function `f[t_]`, then `Plot[ f[t] , {t,-1,1} ]`.

I'm not sure how to solve the error that comes up.

The Mathematica code is:

```
Clear[moll, f]

moll[x_] := 
Piecewise[ {  {E^(-1/(1 - x^2)), -1 < x < 1} , {0,x <= -1 || x >= 1}  } ]; (* Standard     mollifier *)

f[t_] := D[ moll[t] , t]

f[t]

Plot[%, {t, -1, 1}] (* this line works *)

Plot[f[t], {t, -1, 1}] (* this line comes up with an error *)
```

Comment: If you evaluate e.g. `f[2]`, you'll see why plot doesn't work. You could define the function as `f[t_] = D[ moll[t] , t]` (`Set` instead of `SetDelayed`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `Plot[Evaluate[f[t]], {t, -1, 1}]`

Plot is a bit picky when it comes to user defined functions.

Answer (score 2):

With the given function you could use:

```
Plot[f[t], {t, -1, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

`Evaluated -> True` is to be [preferred](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7832/121) over `Evaluate[f[t]]`.

Better is to follow nikie's advice and define `f` differently:

```
Block[{t},
  f[t_] = D[moll[t], t]
]
```

See [Scoping in assigning a derivative](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6664/121) for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The 'pickyness' of Plot comes from its `Atttributes[Plot]`, which include `HoldAll`, so the unadorned `f` never gets evaluated. Force evaluation as ratatosk suggests.